# Convexity of the electrostatic energy on a Riemann surface

Tags: riemann-surfaces, convexity, green-function, logarithmic-energy

Let $M$ be a compact Riemann surface. 
Let $\Lambda$ be a differentiable real $2$-form of integral one.
Let $G$ be the Green function associated to $\Lambda$, i.e. 
$G: M \times M \to \mathbb R \cup \{\infty \}$ is symmetric,
$G_x(y) = G(x,y)$ is integrable for every $x \in M$
(with respect to any positive differentiable $2$-form),
$\int G_x(y) \Lambda(dy) = 0$ for every $x \in M$ and
     $$\Delta G_x = -\delta_x + \Lambda .$$

It is known that $G$ is bounded from below. Denote by $\mathcal P(M)$ the space
of probabilities in $M$.
We can define the functional
     $$I : \mathcal P(M) \to \mathbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$$
      $$\mu \mapsto \int_{M \times M} G(x,y) \, \mu(dx) \,  \mu(dy).$$

I would like to prove that $I$ is convex. One possible approach is
to try to prove that
    $$\frac{1}{2} \int \mu(dx) G(x,y) \mu(dy) 
  + \frac{1}{2} \int \nu(dx) G(x,y) \nu(dy)
   \geq \int \mu(dx) G(x,y) \nu(dy)$$
for every $\mu, \nu \in \mathcal P(M)$. We can see that this
 is true for differentiable $2$-forms.
To complete the proof I would need the following to be true: 
For any $\mu \in \mathcal P(M)$, there exists a sequence 
$\{\mu_n\}$ of differentiable $2$-forms such that
    $$\mu_n \to \mu$$
weakly and
    $$I(\mu_n) \to I(\mu).$$

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to prove the existence of such sequence or, in any case, another way to prove the convexity of $I$.

Comment: Are there some standart references for the definition of these Green functions ? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if there are standard references. I have this one http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~pbruin/scriptie.pdf .